# Debugging failing jQuery validate addMethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a page where almost every click is handled by delegate().
http://itsneworleans.com/shows/midnight-menu-plus-1/blogs/after-midnight?preview=1

I set up jQuery validate like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".commentform form").validate({
        rules: {
            antispam: { equalToParam: "INO" }
        }                      
    });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("equalToParam", function(value, element, param) {
       return value == param;
    },
    "Anti-spam field does not match requested value.");
});
```

if I check in console with

```
$.validator.methods['equalToParam']
```

I get back

```
function (value, element, param) { return value == param; }
```

so that looks good.

The validation works on the form submission BUT the equalToParam method has no effect.  Only the "required" events occur for it.

The field HTML is

```
<input name="antispam" type="text" class="required" id="antispam" size="5" />
```

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**  Here is whole form code (generated from PHP script and added to page via AJAX):

```
<? if ($post = (int) $_POST['pID']) { ?>
<div class="commentform">
    <form>
    <div class="commenttext">Comment:<br>
        <textarea name="comment" class="required"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="commenttext">Your name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="required">
    </div>
    <div class="commenttext">Your email (will not be publically visible):<br>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="required email">
    </div>
    <div class="commenttext">Type the letters INO here to help us beat spam!<br>
        <input name="antispam" type="text" class="required" id="antispam" size="5" />
    </div>
    <div class="commenttext">
        <input type="button" name="submitcomment" class="submitcomment" value="Submit Comment">
        <input type="hidden" name="post" value="<?=$post?>">
        <? if ($parentComment = (int) $_POST['cID']) { ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="<?=$parentComment?>">
        <? } ?>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

**EDIT AGAIN**  And here's the click delegation code...

```
$("body").delegate(".submitcomment", "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var theform = $(this).closest("form");
    console.log('Posting comment');

    if ($(".commentform form").valid()) {       
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/addComment.php",
          data:  theform.serialize() 
        }).done(function(html) {
            if (html == 'OK') {
                $(theform).html("<div class='commentposted'>Your comment has been received. Thank you.  A moderator will review it for public viewing.</div>");
            } else {
                alert(html);
            }
      });
    }
});
```

**EDIT** Here is the code which populates the form into the space where the Reply to Post link was:

```
$("body").delegate(".getcommentform", "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var pIDval = $(this).attr("data-pid");
    var cIDval = $(this).attr("data-cid");
    var thebox = $(this).closest("div.commentformcontainer");
    console.log('Getting comment form');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/commentForm.php",
      data:  { pID : pIDval, cID : cIDval }
    }).done(function(html) {
        thebox.html(html);          
  });
});
```

Comment: What does your form tag look like? Is this really the right selector? ".commentform form"

Comment: It's `<div class="commentform"><form>...`   And since the validation is otherwise working I assume the selector is correct?

Comment: Working fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/eN52w/1/

Comment: Added whole form generation script code above just now.

Comment: Updated [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eN52w/1/) and it's still working fine for me.

Comment: @Sparky- yeah I know.  It's an all but exact copy of a working form from another job BUT that page isn't using delegate() so I assume(d) there was a delegate() gotcha?

Comment: If you think the problem has to do with click event delegation, don't you think you should show that part of the code?

Comment: Yessss.  I just realized I omitted it.  XD

Comment: Still working:  http://jsfiddle.net/eN52w/2/

Comment: I have no idea what else could be relevant other than a link... http://itsneworleans.com/shows/midnight-menu-plus-1/blogs/after-midnight?preview=1

Comment: There is no form on that page.

Comment: It's added by the Reply to this Post links.  The bring in form via AJAX

Answer (score 0):

When you need to apply the `.validate()` method to more than one `form`, you must wrap it within a jQuery `.each()`.

```
$(".commentform form").each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            antispam: {
                equalToParam: "INO"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT**:

You need to initialize the plugin AFTER the form is inserted into the page.  Assuming this code properly inserts the form... put your `.validate()` call as the last item inside...

```
$("body").delegate(".getcommentform", "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var pIDval = $(this).attr("data-pid");
    var cIDval = $(this).attr("data-cid");
    var thebox = $(this).closest("div.commentformcontainer");
    console.log('Getting comment form');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/commentForm.php",
      data:  { pID : pIDval, cID : cIDval }
    }).done(function(html) {
        thebox.html(html);          
  });
  $(".commentform form").validate({ // <- initialize plugin AFTER form is inserted
      // your rules & options
  });
});
```

---

**EDIT 2**:

Include the `equalToParam` function someplace on your page within a DOM ready event handler.

Comment: Thank you for all of this.  Updated http://itsneworleans.com/js/main.js as specified.  It's at very foot of that file.  Behavior of validate() after Ctrl F5 is still same.  Antispam is required but addMethod validation dioes not occur

Comment: @jerrygarciuh, I just realized that those forms are not even on that page.  What code puts the form into the page?... show us that in your OP.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh, `.validate()` needs to be called **after** you insert the form.  See edited answer.

Comment: OK, pulled initialization from bottom and added to delegate code as above.  Same issue persists.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh, makes no sense.  Where is the custom method `equalToParam` being included in the page?  That's the only part that seems to be broken, right?

Comment: @jerrygarciuh, I don't see `equalToParam` included anywhere in the source code of your page.

Comment: At present it was moved along with the initialization in main.js to inside the delegate() code.

Comment: `jQuery.validator.addMethod("equalToParam", function(value, element, param) { return value == param; }, "Anti-spam field does not match requested value.");`

Comment: And when I issue `$.validator.methods['equalToParam']` in console it prints function

Comment: @jerrygarciuh, I honestly did not feel like digging through that page, but I'm out of ideas.  Looks like it should be working.  One final thought... there's no reason not to include `equalToParam` within the page on DOM ready.

Comment: Thank you for all your time and efforts!  I very much appreciate it.  I added a DOM ready to the foot of the page itself and added the addMethod.  Alas no joy...  If it's any comfort I feel validated that I'm not a complete dope. If I find an answer I'll post back here.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh, I'm sure there's a simple explanation.

Comment: Maybe.  I suspect interference is coming form other scripts.  Maybe jQueryTools... At any rate after all that effort my temporary answer was to check the value in the delegate() script and send my own message and return false...